# How do you configure a Lan to Lan VPN without using your outside interface IP address?

Tags: cisco, vpn, cisco-asa

I have two /28 subnets A & B.

My main vpn peer ip is in subnet A, it is also my outside interface address.

I have free IP's in subnets A and B and id like to use one of them to host lan to lan my vpn connections.

How do I configure one of my free IP's as the vpn peer? I cannot find any options using ASDM or the CLI and I've been googling for hours!

Comment: Show us the relevant configs for the ASAs... sanitize addresses if you like, but understanding this question is currently close to mindreading without a diagram and configs.

Comment: Don't forget to also post the version of ASA you are running. Different code versions can have different syntax or or features.

Comment: I thought with ASAs, if you have a subnet routed to your ASA it will proxy arp by default so you can make configurations with those extra addresses?

Comment: For nat, yes.  For vpn termination, NO. And it's not technically "proxy arp", as it's only answering for the addresses it's handling.

Comment: @RickyBeam You learn something new everyday. That's today covered! Cheers ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Inga alluded, you cannot setup the ASA do this.  It does not support "ip aliases"; it has one, and only one address.  There are no options to configure isakmp / ikev(1|2) on it's own address. (it's either enabled on an interface or not.)

(And if you get the bright idea to put a free address on a second interface, it won't allow subnets to overlap.  However, you could assign "B" to it's own interface, but you'd still be terminating traffic to the ASA's interface address.)

Comment: The problem is I've shifted the rest of the vpns already to the new device but both firewalls have external IP's in the same subnet!! /cry
Thanks anyway though. Great help.

Answer (score 3):

Either you configure your asa as the vpn peer itself ( and therefore use the ip address already assigned to the ASA) or you configure a static nat and therefore map 1 "external" ip to 1 "internal" Ip permanently. You are then able to terminate the vpn tunnel on the device "behind" the firewall ( given that you have adapted the access-lists accordingly).

I think you probaly want a) but it all really depends on your setup , so i'll highly opt for  your configuration  and diagram  of your setup too :-)

Comment: Actually he doesn't want a or b.  He wants the ASA to terminate VPN traffic on an address that isn't the outside address.

Comment: This is actually a good idea as a work around. Might just create a new security context on the asa though.. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: moodah - context are not equiped for vpn... and anyway this is probably really not the way to go...